# Does jest auto mock missing dependencies even when auto mocking is disabled?

Tags: reactjs, decorator, jestjs, enzyme

[I wrote a decorator simplify smart/dumb components separation in ReactJS](https://github.com/borela/presentable), at one point I tried to break the test code into multiple files and moved the [colaborator classes to the __mocks__ directory](https://github.com/borela/presentable/tree/master/src/__mocks__).

The file structure became:

```
src
  __mocks__
    SharedComponent.js
    SomeComponent.js
    SomePresenter.js
    SpecificPresenter.js
  __tests__
    index.js
  index.js
```

In the test file `index.js`, to load the `SomeComponent` I do:

```
import SomeComponent from 'SomeComponent'
```

**That class only exist in the mocks directory** and it is used only to test the decorator. [You can see here](https://github.com/borela/presentable/blob/master/src/__tests__/index.js#L15) that I am not mocking that class explicitly and in the [manual says that auto mocking is disabled by default.](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#automock-boolean)

**Does jest auto mock missing dependencies even when auto mocking is disabled?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thanks to Michał Pierzchała in this comment:](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3870#issuecomment-309975329)

> When a manual mock exists for a given module, Jest's module system will use that module when explicitly calling jest.mock('moduleName'). **However, manual mocks will take precedence over node modules even if jest.mock('moduleName') is not called.** To opt out of this behavior you will need to explicitly call jest.unmock('moduleName') in tests that should use the actual module implementation.